# Java Recursion output

Tags: java, recursion

I have this recursion here, when I input "ello", the output returns "ello".
I thought it would return "ellllloo". Am I not following the recursion right?
It's keep calling FN(str.substring(1));

```
            return str.substring(0, 1) + FN(str.substring(1));
```

Comment: Pencil and a paper for the rescue.

Comment: Side note: you can use 'isEmpty()' instead of querying the length and comparing to 0. And you might want to rework your question until it becomes clear what exactly your recursion should yield as output. Right now, the only thing that can be said is: your recursion is based on letters being a or h; and both letters do not show up in your input. So you always take the "then" path of the second if. What is the surprise there?

Comment: return str.substring(0, 1) + FN(str.substring(1)). yes, so with this "ello", it returns "el"+FN("llo"), and so on, that wouldn't output "ello", but I'm getting "ello" in the output

Comment: ahh i thought the end index is inclusive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'a' or 'h' in the input, so it will always call `return str.substring(0, 1) + FN(str.substring(1));` until the length is 0 :

```
FN("ello") = 
   "e" + FN("llo") = 
   "e" + "l" + FN("lo") = .... = "ello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion each time takes the first letter of the remaining string:

```
  "e" + FN("llo")
= "e" +    "l"   + FN("lo") 
= "e" +    "l"   + "l"     + FN("o") = "ello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
str.substring(0, 2)// instead of str.substring(0, 1)
```